# Why is my main UIView getting pushed down beyond what's indicated in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode

I haven't used Storyboards since I first played around with iOS tutorials. Using one for a project. I have a `UINavigationController` based project. One of my controllers is below:

[image]

And here's the view hierarchy:

[image]

I have all the subviews under the main UIView. And then there's a `Navigation Item`. Now, if I move all the subviews in the main UIView up to the very top of the screen, when I run, they'll appear under the navbar. I can do that for now, but it seem stupid that I should have to do that.

I'm using xcode 5.1 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 7 the UINavigationBar overlays the view. This give a very elegant look when elements like UITableViews pass below it but in static layouts it often does not look very nice. There are a million different ways you can deal with this "issue" but frankly the thing to do is to make sure your root view's x and y variables extends to the top of the screen (0,0). To be thorough you should also add constraints for when you rotate the device.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to hide Navigation bar when scrolling then use this

```
     - (void) scrollWillBeginScroll :(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
         if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < lastOffSet) {
         [toolBar setHidden:YES];
         [[self navigationController] navigationBar] setHidden:YES];
        } else{
         // unhide
     }


 - (void) scrillViewDidScroll :(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      /// blah blah
 lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
 }
```

lastoffer is an instance variable